# Tiered tile fetches with LocalTile then UrlTile

Tags: react-native-maps

I would like to be able to locally cache tiles for a particular region that react-native-maps uses as its first choice, but if the user strays off of that region, it falls back automatically (eg. without manually switching) to a UrlTile source to fetch the tile.

This enables the user to use the app offline but have the ability to automatically also fetch missing tiles when they are online.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and according to [this answer](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/issues/255), you may use [react-native-mapbox-gl](https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl) because it has offline support for downloading tiles (take a look on the [OfflineManager](https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl/blob/master/docs/OfflineManager.md) and [snapshotManager](https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl/blob/master/docs/snapshotManager.md) documentation)